# Calculate count of years

Tags: swift, date, swift2

I have a String data that stores date. Example:

`let dates = ["1-Jan-2015", "1-Feb-2015", "20-Mar-2014", "15-Apr-2014", "12-May-2013", "23-Jun-2012"]`

I need to do a count of how many times did that year occurs, and then store it. So what I require would be something like that

`let years = ["2015" : 2, "2014" : 2, "2013" :  1, "2012" : 1]`

I would like to avoid hard coding it for future growth. Meaning say if I have Year 2020, I cannot be hard coding all the years to store these values.

So the problem here is I've got no idea how should I do this on the overview. In addition, how do I convert the String format to date?

Comment: What exactly is the part you're having trouble with?

Comment: How should it be done? I have no clue or idea on the overview, how should the flow of the codes.

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let dates = ["1-Jan-2015", "1-Feb-2015", "20-Mar-2014", "15-Apr-2014", "12-May-2013", "23-Jun-2012"]
// map the last 4 characters of your string
let years = dates.map{String($0.characters.suffix(4))}
// create a dictionary to store tue frequency
var frequencies:[String:Int] = [:]
// loop through the years
for year in years {
    // increase it
    frequencies[year] =  (frequencies[year] ?? 0) + 1
}

let sortedFrequencies = frequencies.sort{ $0.0 < $1.0 }

print(sortedFrequencies)   // [("2012", 1), ("2013", 1), ("2014", 2), ("2015", 2)]\n"
```

Comment: Thanks. However, anyway to sort it according to ascending order? Meaning 2015 followed by 2014 and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following solution. Use the following function and it will give you the following result in the screenshot

[image]

```
 /// This function will return the array as per your requirement
 func getyears(dates: NSArray) -> NSArray
 {
      var year = [String]()
      let newdates = dates
      var countvalue = 0
      for i in dates {

          let x = i.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
          let startIndex = x.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)
          let lastFourDigitsOfdate = x.substringFromIndex(startIndex)


          for xm in newdates
          {

              let xy = xm.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
              let startIndex1 = xy.endIndex.advancedBy(-4)
              let lastFourDigitsOfdate1 = xy.substringFromIndex(startIndex1)

               if lastFourDigitsOfdate == lastFourDigitsOfdate1
               {
                   countvalue = countvalue + 1
               }
           }
        year.append("\(lastFourDigitsOfdate) : \(countvalue)")

        countvalue = 0
     }


     return getUniqArrayData(year)
 }


 // This function will be required to get an unque array
 func getUniqArrayData<S: SequenceType, E: Hashable where E==S.Generator.Element>(source: S) -> [E] {
      var seen: [E:Bool] = [:]
      return source.filter { seen.updateValue(true, forKey: $0) == nil }
 }


 let dates = ["1-Jan-2015", "1-Feb-2015", "20-Mar-2014", "15-Apr-2014", "12-May-2013", "23-Jun-2012"]


 //Calling the above function
      getyears(dates)
```

Hope this will be helpful.